# Python TypeError: range() integer end argument expected Error

Tags: python, range

I have the following piece of code, and on some point i want to init

the object with range of rows and columns.

When i print both of them, i get a number for each, meaning as far as i understand

it should work on the range method.

Here is the code:

```
class Board(object):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):

        #small values
        if rows < 1 or columns < 2:
            SizeOutOfBoundException

        #large values
        if rows > 20 or columns > 50:
            SizeOutOfBoundException

        self.rows = rows;
        self.columns = columns; 
        self.arr = [[[0,'H'] for x in range(self.rows)] for y in range(self.columns)] # <- ERROR
```

But this is the error i keep getting:

```
self.arr = [[[0,'H'] for x in range(self.rows)] for y in range(self.columns)] 
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got Board.
```

How can i manipulate it to work? and why does this wont work?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are doing to call it and what the output should be?

Comment: I am just trying to init my board with the [0,H] list on each location...

Comment: Note that your `SizeOutOfBoundException` lines are no-ops; they do nothing. Use `raise SizeOutOfBoundException()` if you actually wanted to raise an exception there.

Comment: Another tip: Python doesn't need to use `;` colons. Please do remove them.

Comment: You also don't need the trailing semicolons after the lines `self.rows = rows;` and `self.columns = columns;`

Comment: please post your full code. Seems like you are not showing everything to us.

Comment: @codegeek the code is kinda long. when i manually put numbers on the range method, it works. when i print the type of the rows and columns i get int. i dont know if the whole code will do anything...]

Comment: I am sorry all. this was a stupid error, the constructor was called from another location. i will delete this post, and sorry for the waste of time

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely passing a `Board` object as rows or columns, rather than an integer.

Printing:

```
self.rows
self.columns
type(self.rows)
type(self.columns)
```

just before the line causing an error would help to confirm this, alternatively can you post the code you're using that calls Board(rows,columns)?

Comment: As i stated, i do print the rows and columns... and i get a number

Comment: Can you print the type of rows and columns too?

Comment: When i print the type i get:
4
<__m

Comment: `>>> type(4)`
`<type 'int'>`
Not sure your response is complete?

Comment: <type 'int'>
This is what i get

Comment: in addition, when i manually put numbers in the range method, it works

Comment: TI think you need to post the full code, the way you're running it, and the full output into the original question for us to help you here.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Are you sure the problem is not with indenting may be ? Your constructor is not indented correctly.

```
class Board(object):

    def __init__(self, rows, columns):

        #small values
        if rows < 1 or columns < 2:
            raise SizeOutOfBoundException

        #large values
        if rows > 20 or columns > 50:
            raise SizeOutOfBoundException

        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.arr = [[[0,'H'] for x in range(self.rows)] for y in range(self.columns)]

myboard = Board(3,4)
print myboard.arr
```

The output is:

[[[0, 'H'], [0, 'H'], [0, 'H']], [[0, 'H'], [0, 'H'], [0, 'H']], [[0, 'H'], [0, 'H'], [0, 'H']], [[0, 'H'], [0, 'H'], [0, 'H']]]

Answer (score 0):

[There's nothing wrong with your code](http://ideone.com/clone/Z6Nnij).

Are you instantiating the class?

```
b = Board(10, 10)
print b.arr
```

Comment: i do init it, sending numbers, and still the same error